# Referencing a local relative file in a JSON Schema?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am building a JSON for a REST web service. The schema however has grown to over 1300 lines and I want to split it up across multiple files. I am unit testing my schema against a folder of JSON sample responses using [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) version 2.1.8.

I know you have import types defined in your current file like `{ "$ref": "#/definitions/MyBool" }`, however if I wanted to move the definition of `MyBool` to another file, like `Common.schema.json`, how would I reference it then?

I tried `{ "$ref": "Common.schema.json/definitions/MyBoolean" }`, `{ "$ref": "./Common.schema.json/defintion/MyBoolean" }`, and `{ "$ref": "file://./Common.schema.json/definitions/MyBoolean" }` but none of them work.

The answer on "[Does JSON Schema validation in common-js utils support references?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9083630/254477)" seems like it should work but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I'm loading the schema with:

```java
JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.fromReader(   new InputStreamReader(  JsonSchemaTest.class.getResourceAsStream( "/json/schema/MySchema.schema.json" )  )   );
```

and then validating it with:

```java
JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault().getValidator().validate(   schema,   new InputStreamReader(  getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/json/sample/MyJsonSample.json" )  )   ).isSuccess();
```

FWIW `MyBool` looks like:

```
"MyBool": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "value" :{
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [ "true", "false", "file not found" ]
        }
    },
    "required": ["value"],
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```

When I don't try to extract `MyBool`, the schema validates all my JSON samples correctly.

---

The exception I receive is:

```
com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.exceptions.ProcessingException: fatal: unable to dereference URI "file:/Common.schema.json/definitions/MyBool#"
    level: "fatal"
    uri: "file:/Common.schema.json/definitions/MyBool#"
    exceptionMessage: "\\Common.schema.json\\definitions\\MyBool (The system cannot find the path specified)"

    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.URIManager.getContent(URIManager.java:108)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader$1.load(SchemaLoader.java:108)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader$1.load(SchemaLoader.java:103)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.SchemaLoader.get(SchemaLoader.java:165)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.RefResolver.rawProcess(RefResolver.java:113)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.load.RefResolver.rawProcess(RefResolver.java:50)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.RawProcessor.process(RawProcessor.java:76)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.RawProcessor.process(RawProcessor.java:40)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.ProcessorChain$ProcessorMerger.process(ProcessorChain.java:188)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.ProcessingResult.of(ProcessingResult.java:78)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor$1.load(CachingProcessor.java:127)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor$1.load(CachingProcessor.java:119)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor.process(CachingProcessor.java:108)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationChain.process(ValidationChain.java:106)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationChain.process(ValidationChain.java:55)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.ProcessorMap$Mapper.process(ProcessorMap.java:165)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.ProcessingResult.of(ProcessingResult.java:78)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor$1.load(CachingProcessor.java:127)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor$1.load(CachingProcessor.java:119)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3524)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2317)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2280)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2195)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3934)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3938)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4821)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.CachingProcessor.process(CachingProcessor.java:108)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:83)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.processObject(ValidationProcessor.java:179)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:121)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.processArray(ValidationProcessor.java:149)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:119)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.processObject(ValidationProcessor.java:179)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:121)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:48)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.keyword.validator.draftv4.OneOfValidator.validate(OneOfValidator.java:67)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:100)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.processors.validation.ValidationProcessor.process(ValidationProcessor.java:48)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.core.processing.ProcessingResult.of(ProcessingResult.java:78)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonValidator.validate(JsonValidator.java:103)
    at com.github.fge.jsonschema.main.JsonValidator.validate(JsonValidator.java:123)
    at com.initech.ws.json.BaseJsonSchemaTest.jsonFileShouldValidate(BaseJsonSchemaTest.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Comment: Hello! Can you show the code you use to load your schema? Also, which version are you using?

Comment: @fge I've updated the question with those details, but I have not yet had a chance to try your suggestion.

Comment: Does relative paths mean you get to use things like `..`?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai yes

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you need there is being able to reference your files using an absolute URI.

Supposing you are using the stable version (ie 2.0.2), load your schema using [this method](http://fge.github.io/json-schema-validator/stable/com/github/fge/jsonschema/main/JsonSchemaFactory.html#getJsonSchema%28java.lang.String%29).

Given where your file is located, use:

```
final JsonSchema schema 
    = factory.getJsonSchema("resource:/json/schema/MySchema.schema.json");
```

This means URI resolution in this schema will be made relatively to this (loading) URI; so, refering to your `MyBoolean.json`, you will do:

```
{
    "$ref": "MyBoolean.json#/pointer/into/file"
}
```

If it is located at, for instance, `/json/schema/subschemas` then you will write:

```
{
    "$ref": "subschemas/MyBoolean.json#/pointer/into/file"
}
```

Parents also work etc.

---

Note that as noted in the README, 2.1.x is a development version! I am currently reworking the API...

Answer (score 7):

The following solution worked for me. The path is relative to location where I run mvn goals.

```
"items": {
                "type": "object",
                "$ref": "file:src/xyz/abc/lmn/DeviceRecord.json"
         }
```

Here `file:` is the path from where you are executing the maven goal.

Comment: but then when you go to deploy your schema on a web server the wouldn't the `file:` protocol cause problems?

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I was able to get this working by doing

```
given().when().get("...")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("schemas/the-array-schema.json"));
```

Then in `the-array-schema.json` (in the `/resources/schemas` directory), I have

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "$ref": "the-object-schema.json"
  }
}
```

where `the-object-schema.json` is also in the `/resources/schemas` directory.