# swagger 2.x reference model from other file

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, yaml, swagger

I want to create an API with following spec.:

project-api.json

```
{
"Project": {
    "required": [
        "uuid"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "uuid": {
            "type": "string",
            "format": "string"
        }
        "Tasks": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "models/task.json"
                }
            }
        }
...
```

task.json

```
{
"Task": {
"required": [
    "uuid"
],
"properties": {
    "user": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "title": {
        "type": "string"
    },
...
```

Instead of making a reference to models/tasks.json, the generated api generates:

```
List<ModelstasksJson>
```

Anyone know how to reference to models from another json file?

Comment: Generated using swagger-codegen?

Comment: Are you asking how to split your schema definition across multiple files like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179137/how-to-manage-multiple-json-schema-files?

Comment: This would only ever happen if the resolver couldn't find the reference `models/task.json`.  Please share more if you're still having an issue with this.

Comment: @fehguy i still have issues with this, i think swagger is not capaple of resolving local paths when their not in URL form like http://...