# Can declare your JSON Schema by a reference to type?

Tags: java, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a small bit of JSON like:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "message": "all's good!"
}
```

which works with the schema:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "success": { "type": "boolean" },
        "message": { "type": "string"  }
    }
}
```

however it fails with the schema

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "response": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "success": { "type": "boolean" },
                "message": { "type": "string"  }
            }
        }
    },

    "type": { "$ref": "#/definitions/response" }
}
```

with the error

> java.lang.AssertionError: schema resource:/json-schema/sample.schema.json was > invalid: fatal: invalid JSON Schema, cannot continue
>   Syntax errors:

```
[ {
    "level" : "error",
    "message" : "value has incorrect type (found object, expected one of [array, string])",
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "resource:/json-schema/sample.schema.json#",
        "pointer" : ""
    },
    "keyword" : "type",
    "found" : "object",
    "expected" : [ "array", "string" ]
} ]
```

> level: "fatal"

are you not allowed to use a reference for a type outside the definitions section? My motivation is that this is a response to a singular case, but there are cases where this structure is nested in others as well.

If it matters I'm using [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator) version 2.2.6.

---

**PS -** this is a simplified example, the actual schema is more complicated as to justify why reuse and not copying and pasting is desirable.

Comment: I am confused as to why you would declare your top level type as a definition. Can you a slightly more complete example? You can reuse definitions among properties and property values.

Comment: @AdamRosini I have one call that returns a response, but I also have a second call that does batch work returns a map of 1 ids to responses. I want to reuse the response declaration. To be able to reuse the definition AFAIK it has to be in a definition, or can you reuse non-definition type in another file?

Answer (score 2):

You can use "id" and "$ref".

id for identifying, e.g.:

```
{
    "type": "object",
      "id": "#response",
      "properties": {
        "success": { "type": "boolean" },
        "message": { "type": "string"  }
       }
  }
}
```

And then you use $ref, e.g.:

```
"some": { "$ref": "#response" }
```

or external ref:

```
"ext": { "$ref": "http://url.com#response" }
```

See
http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-core.html#anchor27

Answer (score 1):

The value of the `type` keyword must be a string of the name of one of the JSON primitave types (e.g. "string", "array", etc.), or an array of these strings.  That is what the error message is saying.  Keyword `type` must be a string or an array.  The closest thing to what I think you are trying to do is this ...

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "response": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "success": { "type": "boolean" },
                "message": { "type": "string"  }
            }
        }
    },
    "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/response" }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your definition in it's own file, and they have your types refer to that file reference. See [How to manage multiple JSON schema files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179137/how-to-manage-multiple-json-schema-files) for details.